# Getting all tags from my different records

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I use EntityFramework on my ASP.NET MVC project.

Let's say I have the entity below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Lets say I have the following data in my DB:

```
ProjectID: 1
Description: "My first element"
Tags: "one, three, five, seven"

ProjectID: 2
Description: "My second element"
Tags: "one, two, three, six"

ProjectID: 3
Description: "My third element"
Tags: "two, three, four"
```

I would like to collect all tags from all my records. So: "one, two, three, four, five, six, seven"

How can I do? This may seems a stupid question but I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: Is order unimportant?  For example, would "one, three, five, seven, two, six, four" be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `string.Split()` to dig out each tag in your list.

```
HashSet<string> allTags = new HashSet<string>();
foreach(Project project in context.Projects)
{
    string tagsList = project.Tags;
    string[] separateTags = tagsList.Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach(string separateTag in separateTags)
    {
        allTags.Add(separateTag);
    }
}
```

then `allTags` will contain all your tags. If you want to put them in one big string again, use `string.Join`.

Answer (score 0):

After splitting the strings you can use [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx#Y0) to concatenate the collections, and then use `Distinct()` to remove duplicates.

```
var tags = context.Projects
               .SelectMany(p => p.Tags.Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
               .Distinct();
```

Here is the query syntax version, which gets transated to a `SelectMany()` statement behind the scenes:

```
var tags = (from p in project
            from tag in p.Tags.Split(", ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            select tag).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Split() won't translate to SQL, so you have to do that in memory. I'd recommend the following:

```
var tags = context.Projects
    // pull only the tags string into memory
    .Select(p => p.Tags) 
    // operate in memory from this point on
    .AsEnumerable()
    // remove empty entries so you don't get "" interpreted as one empty tag
    .SelectMany(tags => tags.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    // assuming you don't want leading or trailing whitespace
    .Select(tag => tag.Trim())
    .ToList();
```